# An error occurred in Pyspark groupby code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WBpvZQ_6Gmpy6qDyJW7Xw2gXqs5iGh_8mtx4Wh1gbKE/edit?usp=sharing) on which I was asked to write a pyspark code for the following question.

```
List of Players with number of times they have won Tournament in descending order(Max to min).
Result attributes: player_name, number_of_wins
```

I wrote this code:

```
game_info = spark.read.load("/content/chess/chess_wc_history_game_info.csv",
                     format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")

game_info.groupBy('winner','event','tournament_name').count().show()
```

But on execution it's returning some events as :

```
FIDE WCh KO
FIDE-Wch k.o.
```

I need to discard the rows having such events ending with `k.o.` or `KO`. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: you could use [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-filter) with the [`like`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.like.html#pyspark-sql-column-like) operator

Comment: The question has asked for 2 result attributes: `player_name`, `number_of_wins`. Shouldn't `winner` and its `count()` sufficient to achieve this? You should not need `event` and `tournament_name`.